# Why do PasswordDeriveBytes and Rfc2898DeriveBytes produce different results?

Tags: c#, encryption

I used to have the following code to get my password derivatives using SHA1:

```
string passPhrase = "Pas5pr@se";        
string saltValue = "s@1tValue";        
string hashAlgorithm = "SHA1";             
int passwordIterations = 2;      

PasswordDeriveBytes password = 
    new PasswordDeriveBytes (passPhrase, saltValueBytes, hashAlgorithm, passwordIterations);
```

Then I get the bytes by doing:

```
var bytes = password.GetByes(32);
```

I saw that I should use Rfc2898DeriveBytes instead. So I now replace it with:

```
Rfc2898DeriveBytes password1 = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passPhrase, saltValueBytes, passwordIterations);
```

But when I do:

```
 var bytes = password.GetBytes(32);
```

I don't get the same values. Any clue?

Comment: Well why would you *expect* to get the same values when you're using two different algorithms to derive the passwords?

Comment: Is not the same? I read that Rfc2898DeriveBytes uses SHA1 by default.

Comment: It uses HMACSHA1. I don't know enough about the details to know whether that's meant to come out the same way, but it doesn't particularly surprise me that it doesn't.

Comment: I *hope* you aren't using 2 iterations in the real world and that's example code. This should be a much larger number like 250,000 in an ideal world.

Answer (score 4):

`Rfc2898DeriveBytes` uses PBKDF2, while `PasswordDeriveBytes` uses a modified version of PBKDF1. They are not compatible with one another.

Given that this is a MACing function, you cannot convert them from one to another, either.

If you want to start using Rfc2898DeriveBytes, you'll need to do it for new data only, and continue to use `PasswordDeriveBytes` for old data or user passwords.

Comment: Which is a good reason to always include a version indicator.